# Ceilometer independently **WITHOUT OpenStack**

Tags: openstack

I would like to use Ceilometer independently **WITHOUT OpenStack** to get usage data from VMWare vSphere installation.

Can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: *"Can anyone please guide me on this."* - Start by asking a question that states what you actually want to do ... and that has vmware-related tags.  Clearly, Ceilometer is not a viable solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ceilometer is designed specifically for Openstack and I don't think so it would fit for your usecase.

Comment: hi,I am actually  looking for celiometer equivalent of service or SDK to  get usage data from VMWare vSphere  Vcenter environment.

Can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: @user2309725 - In that case, you have asked the wrong question, with the wrong tags.

Answer (score 1):

Ceilometer is designed specifically for OpenStack.

But for vSphere, there are only two tools that I know of (other than manually going through the data in vSphere) which is free and both have some limitations.

RV Tools from Roboware will allow you to get the utlization of the environment in excel sheet. Please do remember that it is a point in time snapshot.

You can also use products like Veeam one Free ... This only stores last 24 hours data.

Commercial solutions would include Veeam one, or VROps, or VM Turbo, etc.